# Do loop not working on findrange for user input

Tags: excel, vba

Can anybody help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? The following loop to copy specific rows of data is not working for me. I am trying to create a prompt that will match the cell value in column "A" I specify and the date from column "AN" that I specify. The entire row from the matching row will copy over.

```
Sub Yo2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
' Use last cell in UsedRange for its row number,
Dim lastrowsheet2 As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Location File Data").UsedRange
    lastrowsheet2 = (Sheets("Compare").Range("D3"))
    If lastrowsheet2 = 1 And .Cells(1).Value = "" Then lastrowsheet2 = 0
End With

Dim userinput As String
userinput = InputBox("Enter a value to search for.", "Column A Search")
Dim findrange As Range
Dim firstaddress As String
Set findrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Find(what:=userinput, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
If findrange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No matching search results"
Else
    firstaddress = findrange.Address
    Do
        Set findrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("AN").Find(what:=userinput, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If findrange Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No matching search results"

        Else
            firstaddress = findrange.Address        
            lastrowsheet2 = lastrowsheet2 - 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Location File Data").Range("A" & lastrowsheet2 - 1, "AN" & lastrowsheet2 - 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & findrange.Row, "AN" & findrange.Row).Value
            Set findrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").FindNext(findrange)

    ' Loop until the Find has wrapped back around, or value not found any more
    Loop While Not findrange Is Nothing And findrange.Address <>firstaddress
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: What's not working? An error (which line)? Your logic?

Comment: @PeterT It's just telling me at the Loop that I have a loop without a do. This worked fine when I only had one findrange prompt in, the first one for the cell value prompt in column A. I repeated within the loop so that the date in column AN matched as well when prompted, since many ID's have multiple entries as they have been entered in multiple years, one line for each year. An ID from Column A and specific date from AN gives me a unique line. But I messed up in including the second findrange for the date in AN somehow.

Comment: I see your 'Do` and the compiler is unable to match the `If-Then-End` with the `Do` and `Loop`. The nesting is incorrect.

Comment: I properly indented your code, you should now be able to see where you are missing the `End If` before you `Loop While` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1274820 works perfectly now, thanks!!!

```
Sub Hey()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
' Use last cell in UsedRange for its row number,
Dim lastrowsheet2 As Long
lastrowsheet2 = (Sheets("Compare").Range("D3"))
If lastrowsheet2 = 1 Then lastrowsheet2 = 0
Dim userinput As String, DateInput As String
userinput = InputBox("Enter a value to search for.", "Column A Search")
DateInput = InputBox("Enter a date to search for.", "Column AN Search")
Dim findrange As Range
Dim firstaddress As String
Set findrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Find(what:=userinput, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
If findrange Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "No matching search results"
Else
firstaddress = findrange.Address
Do
    If DateValue(DateInput) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(findrange.Row, "AN").Value Then
        lastrowsheet2 = lastrowsheet2 + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Location File Data").Range("A" & lastrowsheet2, "AN" & lastrowsheet2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & findrange.Row, "AN" & findrange.Row).Value
    End If
    Set findrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").FindNext(findrange)
    ' Loop until the Find has wrapped back around, or value not found any more
Loop While Not findrange Is Nothing And findrange.Address <> firstaddress
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with fixed nesting.

I also took out the duplicate "No matching search results" messages (because you will either not find anything at the beginning or you will have found at least 1 thing).

You're still repeating the first find twice, so it should be reworked further.

Edited to also remove the duplicate `Set findrange =` statement.

Keep in mind, you first do a `Find` - if you find nothing, you display a message and that's it, otherwise, you save the address, then you do whatever your move logic is, then you `FindNext` and you repeat this until you loop around.

I think you also mean to do `lastrowsheet2 = lastrowsheet2 + 1`

I took out the `lastrowsheet2 - 1` from your placement code too because it seems wrong.

Updated to search for date and to fix lastrow (final code)

```
Sub Yo2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
' Use last cell in UsedRange for its row number,
Dim lastrowsheet2 As Long
lastrowsheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Location File Data").UsedRange.Rows.CountLarge
If lastrowsheet2 = 1 Then lastrowsheet2 = 0
Dim userinput As String, DateInput As String
userinput = InputBox("Enter a value to search for.", "Column A Search")
DateInput = InputBox("Enter a date to search for.", "Column AN Search")
Dim findrange As Range
Dim firstaddress As String
Set findrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Find(what:=userinput, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
If findrange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No matching search results"
Else
    firstaddress = findrange.Address
    Do
        If DateValue(DateInput) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(findrange.Row, "AN").Value Then
            lastrowsheet2 = lastrowsheet2 + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Location File Data").Range("A" & lastrowsheet2, "AN" & lastrowsheet2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & findrange.Row, "AN" & findrange.Row).Value
        End If
        Set findrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").FindNext(findrange)
        ' Loop until the Find has wrapped back around, or value not found any more
    Loop While Not findrange Is Nothing And findrange.Address <> firstaddress
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Results:
[image: Results]

Comment: The only thing is I am unable to specify the date that I want to match in the corresponding column AN cell value

Comment: Okay so you want to be able to enter the value to search for and the date to search for? Wouldn't you need two `InputBox`'s for that?

Comment: That's what I was originally trying to do

Comment: Okay well, you need to add a second input - store the date value there. In your `Do` loop, what you need to do is take the value that you found and check to see if the same row, column `AN` contains the date value you stored. You would use `If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(findrange.Row,"AN").Value = OurDateValue Then` and you would include the move code.

Comment: Your `lastrow` code seems wrong - not sure why you read the last row value from `Compare` `D3` - probably need to just set it at the last row of the sheet.

Comment: I updated it again - let me know if it works out for you